# Password field from MySql to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, passwords

I'm trying to hide a password field from a MySql DB to my web app, but i just can't, I'm using a label to show the password field from the DB like this:

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox">
           <?php echo $data['password'];?>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But i want to hide the password, and i can't find any way to to it..

Comment: How is [tag:Java] related here?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap is JavaScript (and CSS) *not* Java; they're not the same thing.

Comment: use  class  hidden to hide the div  : <div class="control-group hidden">

Comment: see this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-show-hide

Comment: As an aside - you should **never** be able to retrieve a password from the database (assuming that's what `$data['password']` is); it should be stored as a [salted hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). So if what you're attempting *is* possible, it means your system is designed incorrectly.

Comment: If you want to hide the password then **why are you *using a label to show the password field* in the first place**?!

Comment: You're not storing passwords as plain text... please tell me you're not storing passwords as plain text.  If you are storing passwords as plain text then please stay away from anything remotely related to computer security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="pw" type="password" value="<?php echo $data['password']; ?>">
```

Then you can use a button and JS to change `type="password"` to `type="text"`

```
var pw = document.querySelector('#pw');           // input
var seePw = document.querySelector('#see-pw');    // button

seePw.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    pw.setAttribute('type', 'text');
});

seePw.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    pw.setAttribute('type', 'password');
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that i dont want it to be an input, it can't be editable by anyone :/

Comment: add `readonly` at the end: `<input id="pw" type="password" value="<?php echo $data['password']; ?>" readonly>`

Comment: The fact that it worked means you're storing passwords in the clear so your security model is broken ... time to start over.

Comment: Just another question about the button and JS, after I place the script, how do I add the button to do it?
Smt like {<input type="checkbox" onclick="Function()">Show Password} ??

Comment: For a clean code, I wouldn't recommend to use onclick in HTML. Name your checkbox with the id `see-pw` if you want to use the same as I used in the example. Then add your functions before closing the Body, and it should work!

Comment: Also, in my example, I used `mousedown` and `mouseup` so it's only visible if the user is clicking on mouse and the password back to hidden when the user release the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php //echo $data['password'];?>
```

may help you
PS nothing to do with java

Comment: But i want to add a "Show password" button too, i just want it to be in pw characters

Comment: "But i want to add a "Show password" button to" Really? @CarlosSantiago passwords should be hashed stored in the database... If the user has forgotten his/her password use a random password generator and reset the password and send the temporary password within a email request.

Comment: This is just a basic school thing, i don't need nothing too specific or too protected!

Answer (score 0):

May one of the following is the solution for you.

1. You can add the class hidden to the element.
2. Use HTML form field as:

```html
    < input type="password" value="echo $data['password'];" disabled>
```

Comment: The only problem is that i dont want it to be an input, it can't be editable by anyone :/

Comment: I have edited my answer, Add the "disabled" keyword to the input field. This will make it inactive and the user cannot edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Never retrieve password from your database also present it. Your risky design should be replaced by a password field which sample data.